# Smoothing the discrete acceleration

Tags: filters, filter-design, impulse-response, moving-average, derivative

In order to know if my signal is increasing or decreasing, I'm using the discrete derivative $y[n] = x[n] - x[n-1]$
or a smoothed version of it (for example Exponential Weight Moving Average of $y[n]$ that gives a "smooth" version of the derivative).

Now to make further analysis, I also want to consider the discrete acceleration:

$$z[n] = x[n] - 2 x[n-1] + x[n-2]$$

But as the signal is sometimes a bit noisy, I wanted to study a **smoothed** version of this acceleration. I thought about :

- Standard Moving average of $z$ : $SMA(z[n], 10)$. Easy computation shows that $SMA(z[n], 10) = \frac{1}{10} (x[n]-x[n-1]-x[n-10]+x[n-11])$

  *It's not so good because it uses too few values of x[k]...*
- Exponential Moving average of $z$ : $EMA(z[n], 10)$. Computations shows that: $EMA(z[n], 10) \approx 0.09 (x[n] - x[n-1])$ and this is proportionnal to ... derivative !

  Indeed, all the next coefficients are negligible $\ll 10^{-3}$.

  *This is strange: I expected the the Exponential Moving Average of the acceleration to be smoother but it turns out that it nearly uses only 2 values : $x[n]$ and $x[n-1]$. (See below the impulse reponse of EMA of acceleration)*.

## Question:

**How to get a "smoothed" version of discrete acceleration, as $A[n] = a_0 x[n] + a_1 x[n-1] + ... + a_k x[n-k]$ ?**

---

Remark: Impulse reponse of EMA of discrete acceleration:

[image]

Comment: What EMA with what $\alpha$'s did you use to smooth the derivative ?

Comment: You should have a look into [Savitzky-Golay filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter).

Comment: @Gilles : I used $\alpha = 1/(1+10)=1/11$ to smooth the derivative. When using same $\alpha$ with EMA to smooth the acceleration, I get this weird result : smoothed acceleration $\approx c (x[n] - x[n-1])$ !

Comment: @MattL. : I didn't know. Why specifically these filters, and not another? (Kalman) etc.  Can you develop into an answer?

Comment: Savitzky-Golay filters work very well for smoothing data, or smoothing derivatives of data. Have a look at [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15643/savitzky-golay-filter-parameters) (this is not about derivatives though). [This question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/987/how-to-find-smoothed-estimates-of-the-derivative-and-second-derivative-of-a-sign) is very similar to yours.